# Create a new variable in data frame with condition over another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, sqldf

I have 2 dataframes like this

df1

```
       date item 
 02/01/2017    A 
 09/01/2017    B
 14/01/2017    C
```

df2

```
      date1       date2  item    prm
 01/01/2017  03/01/2017     A    YES
 08/01/2017  10/01/2017     B    YES
 15/01/2017  17/01/2017     C    YES
```

Purpose

The `prm` variable is a constant variable, it has the just 1 value.
I'd like to add the variable `prm` in my df1 with this condition

```
df1$date is between df2$date1 and df2$date2 and df1$item=df2$item
```

But, if the condition don't match, then I need that `prm` gets the value "NO"

Comment: This is a simple non-equi join in data.table

Comment: I tried with data.table but my df pass from 1 800 000 rows to 800 000 rows don't know why because when i do a unique i still have 1 800 000 rows

Comment: Try `library(data.table) ; setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), on = .(item, date >= date1, date <= date2), prm := i.prm]` (assuming the date formats are correct)

Comment: Nice thank you it works fine like all the solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *non-equi joins* and *update on join* which are available with `data.table` this becomes:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), on = .(item, date>=date1, date<= date2), prm := i.prm][
  is.na(prm), prm := "NO"]
df1
```

> ```
>          date item prm
> 1: 2017-01-02    A YES
> 2: 2017-01-09    B YES
> 3: 2017-01-14    C  NO
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse` here

```
 df1 <- read.table(text = "      date item 
 02/01/2017    A 
 09/01/2017    B
 16/01/2017    C", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "      date1       date2  item
 01/01/2017  03/01/2017     A 
                  08/01/2017  10/01/2017     B
                  15/01/2017  17/01/2017     C", header = T)

df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df2$date1 <- as.Date(df2$date1, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df2$date2 <- as.Date(df2$date2, format = "%d/%m/%Y")


df1$prm <- ifelse(df1$date >= df2$date1 & df1$date <= df2$date2 & df1$item == df2$item, "YES" , "NO")

        date item prm
1 0002-01-20    A YES
2 0009-01-20    B YES
3 0016-01-20    C YES
```

Comment: Yes it works but i think that my explanation was not good enough i'll edit my question

Comment: Orhan is there anything missing from the answer?

Comment: Does `0002-01-20` looks like a valid date to you? This should be `df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using dplyr:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 = tribble(~date, ~item,
             "02/01/2017",    "A",
             "09/01/2017",    "B",
             "16/01/2017",    "C")

df2 = tribble(~date1, ~date2, ~item,
"01/01/2017",  "03/01/2017",     "A",
"08/01/2017",  "10/01/2017",     "B",
"15/01/2017",  "15/01/2017",     "C")

df3 = merge(x = df1, y = df2)


df4 = as.data.frame(cbind(df3[1], lapply(df3[2:4], as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")))


df5 <- df4 %>%
  mutate(prm = if_else((date > date1) & (date < date2), "YES", "NO"))

df5
```

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT]

In case the number of rows in `df1` and `df2` is different, you can use `sqldf` and create an `LEFT JOIN` on `df1.date between df2.date1 and df2.date2` and `df1.item = df2.item` and use a `CASE WHEN` statement to create the column `prm`:

```
options("stringsAsFactors" = FALSE)

df1 <- read.table(text = 
"date item 
02/01/2017    A 
09/01/2017    B
16/01/2017    C 
02/01/2017    C",
header = TRUE)
df2 <- read.table(text =
"date1       date2  item
01/01/2017  03/01/2017     A 
08/01/2017  10/01/2017     B
15/01/2017  17/01/2017     C",
header = TRUE)

library(sqldf)


sqldf("
  SELECT df1.*, CASE WHEN df1.item = df2.item THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS prm
  FROM df1 
  LEFT JOIN df2 
   ON df1.date BETWEEN df2.date1 AND df2.date2
   AND df1.item = df2.item
  ")

        date item prm
1 02/01/2017    A yes
2 09/01/2017    B yes
3 16/01/2017    C yes
4 02/01/2017    C  no
```

Comment: It works but same problem than with data.table i don't know why, before the sqldf my data frames had 1 800 000 rows and after it has 800 000 rows

Comment: Is it because only 800,000 rows meet the date AND item criteria? I have changed the join to `LEFT JOIN`, is that what you are looking for?